# Git: How to Undo commit *and* revert to last branch

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

Uh oh... I mistakenly committed a pretty complex change (including subdirectory and files renames) without really knowing what I am doing (or what Git would be doing).

I now want to undo everything such that:

1. commit is completely reversed (as if
   it has never been done, perhaps
   removing it from history as well)
2. Restore current working directory
   (where `.git` is) to a certain
   branch (last one will do for now).

I found references to [git reset --soft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit/927386#927386) and [git reset --hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923055/how-to-move-a-branch-backwards-in-git/2923142#2923142) but I have already proven to myself that I can do real damage by prematurely using a command without fully understanding it. :)

I found the [git reset man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) but I am still confused as to:

1. What is `HEAD`?
2. What is the difference between
   `HEAD` and `* master`?
3. In my situation (see above) do I
   need to use `--soft`, `--hard` or
   other (3 more options)?
4. Do I need to run another command
   (after doing `git reset`) to
   "finalize" the reversal?

**UPDATE:** After reading the answer below:

1. Do I understand correctly that all I
   need to do in my situation is issue
   a single command `git reset --hard
   HEAD^`?
2. How do I verify that reversal was
   performed correctly?

Comment: Since you are learning git, let me recommend two books to you: [git community book](http://book.git-scm.com/index.html) and [pro git](http://progit.org/book/), which are both completely online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `HEAD` is the latest commit of the checked-out branch.
2. `master` is a branch (the main branch, by convention) whereas `HEAD` is a location in history for the checked-out branch. `HEAD` is relative to the branch you are on.
3. `git reset --soft` will leave your changes in the working tree, uncommitted for you to do whatever you like with. `git reset --hard` will restore the working tree to the state it was in at the commit you reset to.
4. No other command is needed.

First, to keep the commit in case you want to inspect it later, make a branch:

```
git checkout -b my_bad_commit
```

(or alternatively do `git branch my_bad_commit` as mentioned in larsman's comment.)

Then return to `master` or whatever branch you were on and reset:

```
git checkout branch_with_bad_commit
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

HEAD^ translates to "the parent of HEAD," which you can even stack for HEAD^^ = 2 commits back. For more on this topic, check the git community book chapter on [undo in git](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html)

Comment: The `checkout -b; checkout` sequence can be done using a single `branch` command.

Comment: Good point to mention that. I have so many aliases I just do `git cob new_branch_name` that I forget the real ones sometimes.

Comment: @Shelhamer Performing both `git checkout master` **and** `git reset --hard HEAD^` took me **two** commits back. This is not what I wanted. I only needed to go one backward. Something must have not been clear in my question.

Comment: @WinWin, there may have been some miscommunication if your master branch did not contain the bad commit (which is why I said "...or whatever branch you were on," meaning to checkout that branch. If you have lost a bit of history you need back, use `git reflog` to recover it. It will list previous `HEAD`s which you can checkout or reset.

Comment: @Shelhamer Thanks for the `git reflog` tip. The links to the books are invaluable. It will take me time to gobble them though. I am still unsure why `git reset --hard HEAD^` alone won't suffice (as I don't really want to keep the commit. That's the point).

Comment: @WinWin, in your question you mentioned wanting the option of keeping the commit somewhere (perhaps removing it history or not). If you truly don't care about the commit, you can just do `git reset --hard HEAD^` on the branch with the bad commit to point HEAD at the commit before the bad one, as if the bad one never existed.

Answer (score 1):

1. `HEAD` is the [tip of the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly).
2. The difference between `HEAD` and `master` is that `HEAD` changes when you checkout a branch (or commit).
3. `--soft` will leave the changes around, so you can re-add/commit them or undo them by doing `git checkout` on the changed files. `--hard` will reset the working area to the state of the commit you are resetting to.
4. Not if you `reset --hard`. You might have to `git push --force` to remote repos (although, if the changes you made are already on a remote, rewriting history is strongly discouraged).

Comment: Thanks +1. Fortunately, I haven't pushed anything yet. So, `git reset --hard HEAD^` alone do the trick for me?

Comment: If you want to undo only the last commit, yes. To be on the safe side, you can also do `git branch mistake` before the `git reset --hard`; if anything goes wrong, you can then `git merge mistake` to get the mistaken commit back.

Comment: OMG after using CVS for so many years, I feel like a total rookie in this world of git. :)

Comment: Oddly, I could never wrap my head around CVS or SVN, but switching to Git felt like coming home ;)