# How to restore multiple branches to their earlier state?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches (B1, B2)

```
            B1 
           /   
C1 - C2 - C3
           \
            B2
```

and I was changing them by turns (checkout->amend->checkout->amend->...). But after a certain time it was a mess, I have to start from the beginning. I found a certain commit in `git reflog` that was OK yet. But how to restore both branches to the commits where that certain commit happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move a branch backwards in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923055/how-to-move-a-branch-backwards-in-git)

Comment: this possible duplicate is not what I want

Comment: `git reset --hard` is the way to do so. If that doesn't work for you, then you should explain in more details what the "mess" is, and the result you want.

Comment: @user3719454: from your description it sure looks like that is what you need. If not, please provide more details in your question. Close vote retracted.